# promql query to return the value from a range-vector which occurs maximum no. of times

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to find the value which has come maximum number of times in a range-vector.

Is it possible to achieve the same using promql ?

Please help.

For eg: In a range-vector `(http_request-total[15m])`, I have 10 samples, out of which few samples occur 2 times, 1 sample occur 8 times and others some more times. So, I want to return the sample which has occur max no. of times. (here the sample that has come 8 times)

Comment: VictoriaMetrics adds support for `mode_over_time(m[d])` function for discrete values - see https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/commit/1c641037e86917ed50db77cf86f9fdf9476de8f5 . It will be available in the upcoming release - `v1.38.2`.

Answer (score 0):

PromQL doesn't have a mode function, and in general it wouldn't make sense as Prometheus takes samples via scrapes so it doesn't have the total knowledge required to correctly calculate the mode , and due to noise etc. it's actually pretty unlikely that there'd be any repeated values in the output of a rate.